# Resize image OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, resize

If I have an image called `inImg` and an image named `outImg` how can I resize `outImg` so that it is 75% the size of `inImg`?

Answer (score 75):

If you want 75% along each axis, you should be able to use [cv::resize](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) to do:

```
cv::resize(inImg, outImg, cv::Size(), 0.75, 0.75);
```

Comment: How could I say something like this: `cv::resize(outImg, outImg, cv::Size(), 75% of inImg, 75% of inImg);`

Comment: @Nick, this is exactly what it does.

Comment: I think Nick want to resize outImg to 75% of inImg and not inImg itself.

Comment: hey how does this work with the new function resizeWindow? I don't have resize in opencv3.1

Comment: Using `cv::Size()` without arguments you will get error `ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function resize`

Comment: should be cv::INTER_LINEAR i think

Answer (score 22):

Use `cv::resize`. Following code will resize outImg to 0.75 times the dimensions of inImg with CV_INTER_LINEAR type of interpolation.

```
cv::resize(inImg, outImg, cv::Size(inImg.cols * 0.75,inImg.rows * 0.75), 0, 0, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
```

The 4th and 5th argument should be left 0 or not assigned to take 3rd argument as size otherwise it will scale according to 4th and 5th arguments.
([OpenCV3 resize](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d))