# Ensure constant Mat size OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, size, computer-vision

am using the findContours() function to find a business card in an image, however sometimes the card is very small in the image. It still finds the card but when I go to do further processing on the image I get unexpected results from cards due to the inconsistency in size of the card.

How can I take outImg and ensure it is always of size x,y?

Comment: Maybe your *"further processing"* needs to be scale invariant instead? Can you give some more details and maybe examples of good/bad images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cv:resize`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23984222/661211) to do it. Unlike in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23984222/661211), You provide a desired-size [`cv::Size`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#size) structure and leave the scale factor arguments.

```
cv::resize(theSourceOfAllEvil,myAwesomeMatrixResized,cv::Size(width,heigth));
```