# Trying to change the resolution of RTSP video streaming

Tags: python, opencv, resolution, rtsp

I am currently working on a hobby project, which is video streaming from an IP camera (Giroptic 360) on RaspberryPi 3 board via RTSP.

I am particularly interested in its URL link used to connect to said camera:

```
rtsp://[IP address]:[Port]/PSIA/Streaming/channels/2?videoCodecType=H.264
```

I am wondering if there's *such a thing* as changing the streamed resolution directly from the URL link (by adding more parameters?) and if there's any more extra functionalities available through the URL link?

** I have tried changing the resolution via openCV's

```
cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1000)
cap.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 500)
```

But it still gave me the default 2048x1024 resolution.

Answer (score 3):

No, you won't have anyway of commanding via the RSTP link using the opencv built in functions. These work at driver level and all the RTSP link provides is a place to pull frames from.

If you want to resize the images, you can do this after you grab the frame using [OpenCV resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984191/resize-image-opencv)

If you want to size the stream itself, then you will need to *recode the stream at the source* i.e. go into the settings and change it. Although you may not have access to this if it is somebody elses stream, you dont have permissions etc.